# tr '\n\t+' command not working in shell bash?

Tags: regex, bash, shell

```
Text1  Text2
(3 tabs)  text 3
(4 tabs)  text 4
 (2 tabs) text 5
Text2 Text7
(2 tabs) Text8
```

I have a text file in the above format. Basically what I want to do is that, I want to replace consecutive newline and tabs with a special char. I am using this command

```
tr '\n\t+' '@'
```

I am expecting this output

```
Text1 Text2@text 3@text 4@text 5<br/>
Text2 Text7@Text8
```

this regex is working fine with eclipse find and replace (also with editplus). However `tr` puts everything in one line.

Can anyone tell me what is problem with `tr`, with this regex? And, what is the resolution?

Comment: Tr does not do regexps or multi-symbol replacements. It's one symbol to one symbol translation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@anubhava's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24534069/45375) explains why `tr` doesn't work here, but the pure `sed` solution has a slight drawback (aside from being somewhat difficult to understand): it *reads the entire input file into memory* before performing the desired string substitution (which may be perfectly fine for smaller files).

IF you:

- have GNU `awk` or `mawk`
- and don't mind combining `awk` and `sed`

here's a **solution that doesn't read the entire input all at once**:

```
awk -v RS='\n\t+' -v ORS=@  '1' file | sed '$d'
```

- `-v RS='\n\t+'` assigns to `RS`, the [input] record separator, which breaks the input (potentially across lines) into records based on being separated a newline followed by at least 1 space. Note that it's the use of a regex as the record separator that is not POSIX-compliant and thus requires GNU `awk` or `mawk`.
- `-v ORS=@` assigns `@` to variable `ORS`, the output record separator.
- `1` constitutes the entire `awk` program in this case: it is a common shortcut that is effectively the same as `{print}`, i.e., it simply outputs each input record, followed by `ORS`, the output record separator.
- However, since *every* record, including the *last* one, is terminated with `ORS`, we end up with `\n@` at the end of the output, which is undesired.
- `sed '$d'` simply deletes that last line from the output (`$` matches the last line, and `d` deletes it).

Answer (score 3):

That is wrong use of `tr` command. It lets you translate one character (class) by another but you cannot use it for regex string replacements like this.

You can use `gnu sed` instead:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n\t\+/@/g;' file
Text1  Text2@text 3@text 4@text 5
Text2 Text7@text8
```

There are 2 parts of this sed command:

1. `:a;N;$!ba;`: Appends the current and next line to the pattern space via `N` command (is a loop that reads the entire input up front before then applying the string substitution)
2. `s/\n\t\+/@/g;` Replaces every newline followed by 1 or more tabs by `@`

**EDIT:** Here is a **non-gnu sed** version that worked on OSX also:

```
sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e $'s/\\n\t\t*/@/g' file
```

Comment: The `tr` explanation is helpful, but your `sed` command doesn't replace `\n\t+` sequences with `@`, it just normalizes to `\n\t` - also, it's not clear to me that blank lines even need to be dealt with. Just a heads-up: requires _GNU_ `sed` due to use of control-char. sequences `\t` and `\n`.

Comment: Thanks good points, yes this is gnu-sed. I have edited code to suite the OP's latest edited question.

Comment: Thanks for updating; perhaps you should also make clear that `:a;N;$!ba;`, is a _loop_ that reads the _entire input up front_ before then applying the string substitution. Also, it's better to say "at least 1 tab", not "multiple tabs".

Comment: Thanks I added that extra bit of info.